# Transactional writing to file

Tags: c++, transactions, filesystems

In the program, I download data from the Internet, and this data needs to be saved to disk. I want to know: if writing data to files using std::ofstream is transactional on Windows OS or is it possible that in case of system failure only part of the data will be written to the disk at the time of writing the data?

I tried to google for the answer but didn't find anything.

Comment: @RichardCritten thank you for advice, but i need very lightweight solution

Comment: if you're on windows, maybe you can also see [ReplaceFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-replacefilew) to do the final rename. it keep the file identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, writing to a file, in general, is not atomic, especially when using high level objects like `std::ofstream`, which does its internal buffering and calls upon the underlying operating system to write out the contents of the file in discrete, separate chunks.

The classical approach to implementing reliable atomicity, in this situation, is to write out the new file under a temporary name. When the entire contents are written the file gets closed, then renamed to its permanent name. In this manner the designated file's contents are always read as complete. Either the complete file gets renamed, or not, there is no middle state. If the state is interrupted, the partially-complete file is ignored, and simply gets overwritten on Take 2.

At least, of course, barring the involvement of pesky cosmic rays, and little gnomes, that mess up the rename operation just at the right time, to crash the entire system and leaving its storage in a state of strewn garbage, all over the place. All bets are off in that case, it goes without saying.

Comment: OK, thank you so much! And what about using checkpoints, analyzing which it will be possible to understand whether the file is damaged or everything is saved correctly? Is this the normal approach?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "checkpoints". Perhaps you meant checksums. That's certainly one technique, but I can think of other approaches, too, like simply adding something that only appears at the end of the file, so if it's missing then it's clear that it's complete. But all of that becomes a moot point when using temporary files and renaming the file only when its complete. By definition, only complete files will be readable when their permanent name is opened.

Comment: Using temporary files looks like an interesting solution, but it requires a complete write-down of the data from scratch every time new data is available. In this case, write operation can take a long time.

But, if we just append data to the end of the file, i think it will be done very fast. Therefore, i think writing special data at the end of the file looks like a good solution. What do you think about that?

Comment: I tend to postpone most of my thinking until I have some actual, concrete code to look at, and evaluate. What's important here is not a single, specific approach, but to have a full understanding of all the issues, understanding of how things work, and then based on that make an intelligent design choices.